# Another PGS4A build error

Tags: android, python, pygame

Let me start out by saying that I am using PGS4A-0.9.6, I have the android-8 SDK installed, and I am using ubuntu 14.10.
I was quite innocently following the instructions to build an APK with PGS4A when out of no where I was hit with this nasty error:

```
Resolved location of library project to: /home/kleber/Desktop/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk/extras/google/play_apk_expansion/downloader_library
Error: Project folder '/home/kleber/Desktop/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk/extras/google/play_apk_expansion/downloader_library' is not a valid directory.
Error: No Android Manifest at: /home/kleber/Desktop/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk/extras/google/play_apk_expansion/downloader_library
```

I am not really sure what this is saying. Could anybody help me out here?

Here is my terminal's output:

```
Updating source code.


Updating build files.

Resolved location of library project to: /home/kleber/Desktop/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk/extras/google/play_apk_expansion/downloader_library
Error: Project folder '/home/kleber/Desktop/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk/extras/google/play_apk_expansion/downloader_library' is not a valid directory.
Error: No Android Manifest at: /home/kleber/Desktop/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk/extras/google/play_apk_expansion/downloader_library

Creating assets directory.


Packaging internal data.

Listing private ...
Listing private/include ...
Listing private/include/python2.7 ...
Listing private/lib ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7 ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/bsddb ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/compiler ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/config ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/distutils ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/distutils/command ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/email ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/email/mime ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/encodings ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/hotshot ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/importlib ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/json ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/logging ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/dummy ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/plat-linux3 ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/pydoc_data ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/site-packages ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/android ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jnius ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/threads ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/sqlite3 ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/test ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/unittest ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/wsgiref ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/xml ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/xml/dom ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/xml/etree ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/xml/parsers ...
Listing private/lib/python2.7/xml/sax ...
Listing flippyfone ...
Compiling flippyfone/flippyfone.py ...

I'm using Ant to build the package.

Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed

The build seems to have failed.
```

Comment: Also: I did not attempt or even want the google play expansions. I don't believe PGS4A forces you to have it either.

Answer (score 1):

I had been dealing with a build.xml error which is the main root of your cause for a while and i followed the steps in this tutorial im linking and it seemed to fix the problem. If when you finish the steps you still get a error, run in cmd android installsdk again then try to build your program.

https://sites.google.com/site/dustinprinehart/current-projects/float-i-pop/proof-of-concept

Comment: Thanks, but I was using Ubuntu, while this is a fix for windows. That being said, I plan to try this again on windows. In that case it could help me.